# Can an ellipse with fixed semi-axis have different values of eccentricity?

Tags: geometry, conic-sections

Warning: this is probably a ridiculous question *but here goes...*

Can an ellipse with a semi-major axis $a$ take on different values of eccentricity $e$? I have seen various places where it seems to assume that the above is implicitly true, but I cannot visualise it. How can I convince myself that it is true, if it is true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the semi-major axis is $a$ and the semi-minor axis is $b$, then the eccentricity is given by
$$
e=\sqrt{1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}}
$$
Thus, by leaving the semi-major axis alone and varying the semi-minor axis, we can get any eccentricity between $0$ and $1$.

$\hspace{6mm}$[image]

Answer (score 2):

The eccentricity depends on the length on the length of the minor axis, too: when $b=a$ the ellipse is a circle, so its eccentricity is zero, and when $b$ approaches zero the eccentricity approaches $1$, all without changing the length of the major axis.